# How to force re-deploy Prisma model to Google Firebase node_modules?

Tags: firebase, orm, node-modules, prisma

I have an app running on **firebase functions** as back-end API with relational database (MySQL) on other server. I use Prisma as ORM.

Every time when my model changes, Prisma needs to generate proxy classes `npx prisma generate`.

All works great from local dev environment, but when deploying to production, firebase **remembers old model**.

As I understand, `npx prisma generate` creates files in `node_modules` which is not re-deployed by default. The only way I found to fix this, is to change the minor version of Prisma in `package.json` and than redeploying.

My patch-fix is to do this version change every time the model changes, but it definitely shouldn't be working like this.

#### The Question:

Can I force firebase to update its `node_modules` content?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a file already named `firebase.json` in the directory just above your functions. In that file there is a place for `predeploy` steps. Commonly it has a lint and a build script already. Something like this

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So in your package.json add a generate script maybe "p-generate"

```
... etc,
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "p-generate": "prisma generate",
    ...etc
```

Then update your predeploy to include this

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run p-generate",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And would put it first etc, so that lint and build use latest.

At least this is my first thought, I am also thinking to back a cloud function with postgres and prisma so will circle back if I encounter bumps, but seems like that would work well. And if you are deploying in automated environment similarly add this generate step right after the `npm install` step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have already generated prisma classes in this case. Adding predeploy scripts is of course a good idea (to not forget about the command etc) but the problem is - that the new classes don't deploy after being already generated.
We now get over this, changing a minor version of prisma in out packages.json file and reainstalling prisma every time when the model changes (we cirle between two minor versions)

Comment: Interesting. I have now setup an express app in a firebase cloud function with the `https.onRequest` handler and prisma + postgres etc. So far have not changed the schema, but will see if hit some issues as the tables change.